# Errors while compiling Aseprite on Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, compiling

I was trying to compile Aseprite on Ubuntu linux, when I got this error:

```
CMake Error at laf/CMakeLists.txt:86 (message):
  set SKIA_DIR/SKIA_LIBRARY/SKIA_LIBRARY_DIR to compile w/skia backend


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/cran/aseprite/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/cran/aseprite/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

What should I do to alleviate this error and install this application properly? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you following [these instructions](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/main/INSTALL.md#linux-dependencies)?

Comment: Also, did you download using `git clone --recursive https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite.git`

Comment: And what command did you use that returned this error?

Comment: Reminder: There is a paid version which gives you binaries and full support.

Comment: @mchild Yes, I am following those instructions. Here is the error I get now:

Answer (score 0):

we have the same problem encountered

check first if you have skia extracted in deps folder

```
$HOME/deps/skia/
```

if that don't solve it i think you copy the wrong code like me

you need to copy the code below the [Linux details](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/main/INSTALL.md#linux-details)

this

```
cd aseprite
mkdir build
cd build
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-stdlib=libc++ \
  -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=-stdlib=libc++ \
  -DLAF_BACKEND=skia \
  -DSKIA_DIR=$HOME/deps/skia \
  -DSKIA_LIBRARY_DIR=$HOME/deps/skia/out/Release-x64 \
  -DSKIA_LIBRARY=$HOME/deps/skia/out/Release-x64/libskia.a \
  -G Ninja \
  ..
ninja aseprite
```

hope that solved it

Comment: It states that I do not have a directory for $HOME/deps/skia/, I will go fix that and see if aseprite works

Comment: I've created the directory, and entered in the commands you listed but it still did not work.

Comment: did you download the skia?

Comment: download the m102 and extract it in the deps. after that rename it skia

Comment: Here's the link [Skia](https://github.com/aseprite/skia/releases). Copy the on named Skia-Linux-Release-x64-libc++.zip